# Transforming xml based on node values

Tags: xslt

My requirement is slightly complex one.I have the following input xml:

```
<results>
   <row>
      <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
      <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
      <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
   </row>
   <row>
      <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
      <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
      <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
   </row>
   <row>
      <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
      <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
      <OBJECTID>extra</OBJECTID>
   </row>
   <row>
      <CASEID>C2</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUEID>I3</ISSUEID>
      <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
      <OBJECTID>3</OBJECTID>
   </row>
</results>
```

I have to transform the above xml to simpler one using XSLT by following the below conditions:

1)First target is to move all the `<CASEID>`'s whose values are same under the new `<CASE>` tag along with `<CASEBA>` node.

For Example:

```
<CASE>
   <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
   <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
</CASE>
```

2)List out all the `<ISSUEID>` &`<ISSUEBA>` whose `<CASEID>`'s are equal in different `<row>`'s and move them under the new tag`<ISSUE>` within the recently created `<CASE>` tag.

For example:

```
 <CASE>
     <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
     <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
     <ISSUE>
        <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
        <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
     </ISSUE>
     <ISSUE>
        <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
        <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
     </ISSUE>
  </CASE>
```

3)List out all the `<OBJECTID>`'s whose `<ISSUEID>`'s are equal in different `<row>`'s and move them under the new `<SOURCE>` tag within `<ISSUE>`tag which will be definitely under the `<CASE>` .
For example:

```
<CASE>
         <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
         <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
         <ISSUE>
            <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
            <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
            <SOURCE>
               <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
            </SOURCE>
            <SOURCE>
               <OBJECTID>extra</OBJECTID>
            </SOURCE>
         </ISSUE>
         <ISSUE>
            <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
            <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
            <SOURCE>
               <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
            </SOURCE>
         </ISSUE>
      </CASE>
```

The final output xml should be as below:

```
<results>
   <CASE>
      <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUE>
         <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
         <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
         </SOURCE>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>extra</OBJECTID>
         </SOURCE>
      </ISSUE>
      <ISSUE>
         <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
         <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
         </SOURCE>
      </ISSUE>
   </CASE>
   <CASE>
      <CASEID>C2</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUE>
         <ISSUEID>I3</ISSUEID>
         <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>3</OBJECTID>
         </SOURCE>
      </ISSUE>
   </CASE>
</results>
```

Please forgive me if I didn't explain my requirement properly. Please do ask me if you need any additional information. It would be really great if someone helps me out.

Comment: XSLT 1 or 2? This makes a big difference in how complex this will get.

Comment: @ G_H, Thanks for the response. I need for XSLT 2. `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version = "2.0">`

Comment: It's a standard grouping application. You'll find examples of grouping code in any XSLT textbook or tutorial. Grouping is much easier with XSLT 2.0 than with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @Michael Kay, Thanks for your suggestion. I will go through the tutorial.

Comment: @Michael Kay, I am executing the XSLT using JDK. Unfortunately it is not identifying `for-each-group` . I should use only XSLT1.0 to accomplish my task. Could you please help me out how to prepare the same thing using XSLT 1.0? I have opened a new thread on SO here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818999/complex-grouping-based-on-node-values-using-xslt-1-0

Comment: Sorry, I don't offer help with XSLT 1.0. I've been using XSLT 2.0 for about 15 years and my memory of 1.0 is fading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 1 you'd have to use a technique called "Muenchian grouping" and things would get a bit complicated. Fortunately with XSLT 2 you can use the `<xsl:for-each-group>` element and the `current-group()` function. The following stylesheet produces the exact output you require for your given input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="caseID" match="row" use="CASEID" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/results">
        <results>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="CASEID">
                <xsl:call-template name="handleCase" />
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="handleCase"> 
        <CASE>
            <xsl:copy-of select="CASEID" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="CASEBA" />
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="ISSUEID">
                <xsl:call-template name="handleIssue" />
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </CASE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="handleIssue"> 
        <ISSUE>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ISSUEID" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="ISSUEBA" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/OBJECTID" />
        </ISSUE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OBJECTID">
        <SOURCE>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </SOURCE>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

You could nest the whole thing, but to keep it readable I've divided it into several named templates. Fortunately when calling another template, the current group context is retained so you can further group within that group.

Comment: Wow! Super!! Thanks for the solution for my complex requirement. Plus one for your quick response.

Comment: I am executing the XSLT using JDK. Unfortunately it is not identifying `for-each-group` . I should use only XSLT1.0 to accomplish my task. Could you please help me out how to prepare the same thing using XSLT 1.0? I have opened a new thread on SO here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818999/complex-grouping-based-on-node-values-using-xslt-1-0