# Slightly complex grouping based on node values using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

My requirement is slightly complex one.I have to use only XSLT 1.0. I could able to get the solution using XSLT 2.0, but I need the solution using 1.0.

I have the following input xml:

```
<results>
       <row>
          <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
          <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
          <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
          <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
          <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
       <row>
          <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
          <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
          <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
          <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
          <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
       <row>
          <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
          <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
          <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
          <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
          <OBJECTID>extra</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
       <row>
          <CASEID>C2</CASEID>
          <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
          <ISSUEID>I3</ISSUEID>
          <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
          <OBJECTID>3</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
    </results>
```

I have to transform the above xml to simpler one using XSLT by following the below conditions:

1)First target is to move all the `<CASEID>`'s whose values are same under the new `<CASE>` tag along with `<CASEBA>` node.

For Example:

```
<CASE>
   <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
   <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
</CASE>
```

2)List out all the `<ISSUEID>` &`<ISSUEBA>` whose `<CASEID>`'s are equal in different `<row>`'s and move them under the new tag`<ISSUE>` within the recently created `<CASE>` tag.

For example:

```
 <CASE>
     <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
     <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
     <ISSUE>
        <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
        <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
     </ISSUE>
     <ISSUE>
        <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
        <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
     </ISSUE>
  </CASE>
```

3)List out all the `<OBJECTID>`'s whose `<ISSUEID>`'s are equal in different `<row>`'s and move them under the new `<SOURCE>` tag within `<ISSUE>`tag which will be definitely under the `<CASE>` .
For example:

```
<CASE>
         <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
         <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
         <ISSUE>
            <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
            <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
            <SOURCE>
               <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
               <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
            </SOURCE>
            <SOURCE>
               <OBJECTID>extra</OBJECTID>
                <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
            </SOURCE>
         </ISSUE>
         <ISSUE>
            <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
            <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
            <SOURCE>
               <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
               <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
            </SOURCE>
         </ISSUE>
      </CASE>
```

The final output xml should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <results>
   <CASE>
      <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUE>
         <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
         <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
            <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
         </SOURCE>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>extra</OBJECTID>
            <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
         </SOURCE>
      </ISSUE>
      <ISSUE>
         <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
         <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
            <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
         </SOURCE>
      </ISSUE>
   </CASE>
   <CASE>
      <CASEID>C2</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUE>
         <ISSUEID>I3</ISSUEID>
         <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>3</OBJECTID>
            <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
         </SOURCE>
      </ISSUE>
   </CASE>
</results>
```

Please forgive me if I didn't explain my requirement properly. Please do ask me if you need any additional information. It would be really great if someone helps me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your previous question ([Transforming xml based on node values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783955/transforming-xml-based-on-node-values)) the answer mentioned about using a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) in XSLT 1.0. In your case, you have nested grouping. You first group by `CASEID`, then group by `CASEID` and `ISSUEID`, and then finally by `CASEID`, `ISSUEID` and `OBJECTID`

This means defining three keys

```
<xsl:key name="case" match="row" use="CASEID" />
<xsl:key name="issue" match="row" use="concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID)" />
<xsl:key name="object" match="row" use="concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID, '|', OBJECTID)" />
```

To group by `CASEID` you would select the first element of each group like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('case', CASEID)[1])]" mode="case" />
```

(I am using `mode` here because the final XSLT will have multiple templates matching `row` so you need to distinguish between them).

In the matching template, to then group by `ISSUEID` within the distinct `CASEID` values, you would do this.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('case', CASEID)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('issue', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID))[1])]" mode="issue" />
```

You would then do similar to group by `OBJECTID` in the other template.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="case" match="row" use="CASEID" />
    <xsl:key name="issue" match="row" use="concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID)" />
    <xsl:key name="object" match="row" use="concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID, '|', OBJECTID)" />

    <xsl:template match="results">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('case', CASEID)[1])]" mode="case" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="case">
        <CASE>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CASEID|CASEBA" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('case', CASEID)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('issue', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID))[1])]" mode="issue" />
        </CASE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="issue">
        <ISSUE>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ISSUEID|ISSUEBA" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('issue', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('object', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID, '|', OBJECTID))[1])]" mode="object" />
        </ISSUE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="object">
        <OBJECT>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="OBJECTID|OBJECTBA" />
        </OBJECT>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's awesome. Nice explanation. I have one more question . If I don't have the `<CASEID>` in a `<row>`, grouping should be done based on `<ISSUEID>`, If I don't have `<ISSUEID>`, then grouping should be done on `<OBJECTID>`. To summarize, I have to get all the data based on  some kind of `if, else if, else ` logic. Could you please guide me on that?

Comment: Plus one for your neat explanation.

Comment: I think you might need to ask a new question with these new requirements, as it may be a bit difficult to explain clearly just in comments. It would depend if you still want a `<CASE>` tag to be output, for example, and also on whether all of the `row` elements had no `<CASEID>` or if only some didn't and others did.

Comment: If I have the `<CASEID>`, then `<CASE>` tag should be there. If I have the `<ISSUEID>`, then `<ISSUE>` tag should be there.  If I have the `<OBJECT>`, then `<OBJECTID>` tag should be there. The reason behind this is some of the `row` elements might have `<CASEID>`<ISSUEID>``<OBJECTID>` and some not. I will open a new thread. Just give me few minutes.

Comment: I have opened a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820145/grouping-based-on-the-node-value-if-only-it-exists-using-xslt-1-0