# Grouping based on the node value if only it exists using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

My requirement is slightly complex one.I have to use only XSLT 1.0. I could able to get the solution using XSLT 2.0, but I need the solution using 1.0.

I have the following input xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <results>
       <row>
          <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
          <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
          <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
          <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
          <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
       <row>
          <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
          <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
          <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
          <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
          <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
       <row>
          <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
          <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
          <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
          <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
          <OBJECTID>extra</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
       <row>
          <CASEID>C2</CASEID>
          <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
          <ISSUEID>I3</ISSUEID>
          <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
          <OBJECTID>3</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
       <row>
          <ISSUEID>I6</ISSUEID>
          <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
          <OBJECTID>10</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
       <row>
          <CASEID>C11</CASEID>
          <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
          <OBJECTID>11</OBJECTID>
          <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
       </row>
    </results>
```

I have to transform the above xml to simpler one using XSLT by following the below conditions:

> If I have the `<CASEID>`, then `<CASE>` tag should be there. If I have
>   the `<ISSUEID>`, then `<ISSUE>` tag should be there. If I have the
>   `<OBJECT>`, then `<OBJECTID>` tag should be there. The reason behind
>   this is some of the row elements might have `<CASEID>` `<ISSUEID>`
>   `<OBJECTID>` and some not. A `<CASE>` can directly have a `<SOURCE>` under it if there is no `<ISSUE>`.

1)First target is to move all the `<CASEID>`'s whose values are same under the new `<CASE>` tag along with `<CASEBA>` node.

For Example:

```
<CASE>
   <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
   <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
</CASE>
```

2)List out all the `<ISSUEID>` &`<ISSUEBA>` whose `<CASEID>`'s are equal in different `<row>`'s and move them under the new tag`<ISSUE>` within the recently created `<CASE>` tag.

For example:

```
 <CASE>
     <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
     <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
     <ISSUE>
        <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
        <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
     </ISSUE>
     <ISSUE>
        <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
        <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
     </ISSUE>
  </CASE>
```

3)List out all the `<OBJECTID>`'s whose `<ISSUEID>`'s are equal in different `<row>`'s and move them under the new `<SOURCE>` tag within `<ISSUE>`tag which will be definitely under the `<CASE>` .
For example:

```
<CASE>
         <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
         <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
         <ISSUE>
            <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
            <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
            <SOURCE>
               <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
               <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
            </SOURCE>
            <SOURCE>
               <OBJECTID>extra</OBJECTID>
                <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
            </SOURCE>
         </ISSUE>
         <ISSUE>
            <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
            <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
            <SOURCE>
               <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
               <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
            </SOURCE>
         </ISSUE>
      </CASE>
```

The final output xml should be as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <CASE>
      <CASEID>C1</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUE>
         <ISSUEID>I1</ISSUEID>
         <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>1</OBJECTID>
            <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
         </SOURCE>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>extra</OBJECTID>
            <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
         </SOURCE>
      </ISSUE>
      <ISSUE>
         <ISSUEID>I2</ISSUEID>
         <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID>
            <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
         </SOURCE>
      </ISSUE>
   </CASE>
   <CASE>
      <CASEID>C2</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <ISSUE>
         <ISSUEID>I3</ISSUEID>
         <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
         <SOURCE>
            <OBJECTID>3</OBJECTID>
            <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
         </SOURCE>
      </ISSUE>
   </CASE>
   <ISSUE>
      <ISSUEID>I6</ISSUEID>
      <ISSUEBA>MEDICAID</ISSUEBA>
      <SOURCE>
         <OBJECTID>10</OBJECTID>
         <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
      </SOURCE>
   </ISSUE>
   <CASE>
      <CASEID>C11</CASEID>
      <CASEBA>MEDICAID</CASEBA>
      <SOURCE>
         <OBJECTID>11</OBJECTID>
         <OBJECTBA>MEDICAID</OBJECTBA>
      </SOURCE>
   </CASE>
</results>
```

Please forgive me if I didn't explain my requirement properly. Please do ask me if you need any additional information. It would be really great if someone helps me out.

Comment: Could you edit your question so that your example include the case where a `CASEID` wasn't present (and where an `ISSUEID` wasn't present either). Thank you!

Comment: @Tim C, Please take a look now. I have edited my input and output xml. I have also edited the required functionality. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim C, In the last two `row`s you can find a row where there is no `<CASEID>` and only`< ISSUEID>` exists and in another row `<CASEID>` exists but no `<ISSUEID>`, but `<OBJECTID>` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still solve this using Muenchian Grouping. If you are grouping by `CASEID` initially, but `CASEID` may not be present, you can define the first key like so

```
 <xsl:key name="case" match="row" use="string(CASEID)" />
```

So, for the first key, `row` elements with no `CASEID` will be matched by an empty string and grouped together.

To group by `INDEXID` within `CASEID`, you can use a key like this, as this will still work with no `CASEID` (as `concat` returns a string)

```
<xsl:key name="issue" match="row" use="concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID)" />
```

To select the distinct `CASEID` records you would then do this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('case', string(CASEID))[1])]" mode="case" />
```

However, in the template that matched the `row` elements for this mode, you would need a `xsl:choose` statement, to check whether `CASEID` existed or not. If they did exist, you would create `<CASE>` element. If not, you would apply the next level key.

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="CASEID">
            <CASE>
                <!-- Apply next key -->
            </CASE>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
              <!-- Apply next key -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="case" match="row" use="string(CASEID)" />
    <xsl:key name="issue" match="row" use="concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID)" />
    <xsl:key name="object" match="row" use="concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID, '|', OBJECTID)" />

    <xsl:template match="results">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('case', string(CASEID))[1])]" mode="case" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="case">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="CASEID">
                <CASE>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="CASEID|CASEBA" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('case', string(CASEID))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('issue', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID))[1])]" mode="issue" />
                </CASE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('case', concat('', CASEID))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('issue', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID))[1])]" mode="issue" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="issue">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ISSUEID">
                <ISSUE>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ISSUEID|ISSUEBA" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('issue', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('object', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID, '|', OBJECTID))[1])]" mode="object" />
                </ISSUE>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('issue', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('object', concat(CASEID, '|', ISSUEID, '|', OBJECTID))[1])]" mode="object" />            
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="object">
        <xsl:if test="OBJECTID">
            <SOURCE>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="OBJECTID|OBJECTBA" />
            </SOURCE>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Superb!  defining `<CASEID>` as string is a nice logic. Thanks for your neat explanation. Plus One for your logic and helping  nature.